# Ideas for introducing databases to Android development students

Tags: java, self-learning, resource-request, databases

I teach an Android development course to students who have had two full years of Java experience - including a year of data structures.  In the past, my students have used services such as Firebase, Parse, and Couchbase to store their data.

Recently, I've had some experience with Cupboard for Android (https://bitbucket.org/littlerobots/cupboard) which maps Java classes to database tables and maps Java class member variables to the table columns.  Cupboard allowed me to create, modify, delete, and query my SQLite database using instantiated objects instead of writing SQL every time.

Now I have a new interest in learning SQLite and in turn teaching it to my students.  I am looking for recommendations of resources for an intro unit on SQLite.

Comment: I could not recommend using an sql db, in an application. SQL is great for ad-hoc queries, but not for creating applications. There are much better choices, such as the ones you mentioned. Having said that, I would definitely read up on 1st, 2nd, 3rd normal form. It is essential, and also transferable to non-relational DBs.

Comment: SQLite rocks. It's free and on billions of devices.

Comment: Why won't you use sql DB for applications? @richard

Comment: @TKSourabh it is probably not what you want, Don't just eat oranges. See http://nosql-database.org/

Comment: I know there are two sides to everything. But I need a reason to why not? The webpage you shared doesn't seem to have anything other than listing No-SQL DBs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQlite is small and as the name suggest "lite" is great for storing data for mobile applications. Apart from that It can easily be used for other small scale web applications without hiccups (100k or more rows).

**Resources**

- The official [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) is great. Also checkout the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) of the sqlite package once you are comfortable with using SQlite.
- [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)'s a tutorial that provides step-by-step guide.
- Also the sqlite page have some [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) for Android Bindings.

That said, SQlite is one of the most tested(tests are larger than code itself) and have a brilliant code base which makes it very suitable for mobile applications.

Comment: Why don't you come by [The Classroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/the-classroom)? It's our main chat room, and you might find it interesting.